# send http request synchronously

Tags: angularjs, http, asynchronous

I have a scenario where the response of one request will contain a token in the response header and I need to attach this token with any other subsequent requests following.
Any suggestions?

Can't use promise because the order of the requests are not defined, can be in any random order.

Below is my $http post code:

```
    var appURL = ''; 
   appURL = serverURL + $backendApis[apiName] + "/?_s=" + $http.defaults.headers.common['Session-Alias'];

         return $http.post(appURL, postParams).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {

            $http.defaults.headers.common['Custom-Access-Token'] = headers('Custom-Access-Token'); 
            if (response.errorCode && response.errorCode != "8233" && response.errorCode != "506717") {
                alert("Sorry, we are not able to provide you a quotation at this stage as we are facing a technical issue. Please get back after sometime to issue a quotation or call us. Sorry for the inconvenience");
            }
        });
```

I just need to wait for my next request to fire until I don't get the respons eof the first one.
Have tried using ajax and setting async to false, but the bad part is that it freezes the entire U.I of chrome, giving user a bad experience.

Comment: A synchronous http request will always block the UI, there is no way to prevent that with a sync request, since your blocking any javascript execution until response. I believe you should explain better how the subsequent request are fired, but generally speaking and with little data, I believe that you just could to set up some mutex that prevent any other http request to fire until this first 'master' request is done.

Comment: what do you mean by ' order of the requests are not defined'? .. the request giving you the token must be the first one to get fired.. right?

Comment: @Sergeon could you please guide me how to set the mutex?

Comment: @pD7 by 'order of the requests are not defined' I mean that I can't necessarily define what will be requested first, as it totally depends on the user which control he/she navigates to and that request will be served.

Comment: You declare some sort of global var to false. You only set that to true when the first request, that brings the token, is completed. On the other way, in the listeners that binds user interaction with http requests, you wait for that var to be true. If the var is false, you queue the action until the token is set. However, now Im thinking you should be able to do that better with promises: see if @Luxor001 answer works.

Answer (score 0):

This generally is a **bad** idea: synchronize something it's async by "design" it's something makes your code smell (what if one of the endpoint is unreacheable? it will hang your application).

But if for whatever reason you need to go this way, you'll still need to use promises, but with a recursive approach:

```
var promises = urls(); //all your urls in an array

function doCall(){

   var appUrl = promises.pop();
   $http.post(appURL, postParams).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {

        $http.defaults.headers.common['Custom-Access-Token'] = headers('Custom-Access-Token');
        if (response.errorCode && response.errorCode != "8233" && response.errorCode != "506717") {
            alert("Sorry, we are not able to provide you a quotation at this stage as we are facing a technical issue. Please get back after sometime to issue a quotation or call us. Sorry for the inconvenience");
        }
    }).then(function(){
        if(!promises.length) //no urls left, kill the process.
          return;

        doCalls(); //go ahead for the next one
    });
}
```

this way, you'll be able to to $http request synchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem is that I am calling this function from everywhere, a button click or any other service call, all are going through this function.There are possibilties that a user requires some Url say for 'login'..and dosen't require other say 'forgot password', or vice-versa, so If by your answer I add all the Urls to promises, then the promise would never be empty and it will keep calling doCalls().